# Extension method is not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

My app is having some wired issue.When I put a debug and check those values update properly.But if it runs without a debug that values not update properly.How to get rid of this issue.

This is my **static extension method.**

```
public static decimal CalculateTotal(this Invoice invoice)
        {
            var subTotal = invoice.SubTotal;
            var total = subTotal;

            if (invoice.Fees == null || !invoice.Fees.Any()) return Math.Round(total, 2);

            foreach (var fee in invoice.Fees.Where(f => !f.IsCancelled).OrderBy(f => f.Precedence))
            {
                var value = 0m;

                if (fee.Percentage.HasValue)
                {
                    if (fee.Total != null) value += fee.Total.Value;
                }

                if (fee.Fixed.HasValue)
                {
                    value += fee.Fixed.Value;
                }

                total += value;
            }

            return Math.Round(total, 2);
        }
```

Above method is calling is as below.

```
 public InvoiceDetail Booking(my parameters)
        {

            var bookingProcessModel = BookingProcessDetails(providerKey, ownerKey, serviceId, petKeys, selectedDates, selectedTimes, selectedExtraServices, selectedResourceId, userType, discount, specialPrices, isProviderPickUp);


            bookingProcessModel.Invoice.CalculateTotal();//here I'm calling that method 

            Catalog.SaveChanges();//data base save

            var invoiceDetailModel = GetInvoiceDetailModel(bookingProcessModel.AppointmentModel, bookingProcessModel.Invoice);

            return invoiceDetailModel;
        }
```

After the above method,Data base saving value is wrong.But when I put a debug on above extension method and check it's working properly.What is the issue ? Any help ?

Comment: In debug mode - does Catalog.SaveChanges() updating values as you are expecting?

Comment: @swapneel If I put a debug on 'bookingProcessModel.Invoice.CalculateTotal()',then it's working properly. :( Otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Your Extension Method returns a `Decimal`, but you're not assigning this to anything...

```
bookingProcessModel.Invoice.CalculateTotal();
```

...is only returning a `Decimal` value, so what you are seeing is the correct behavior.

I don't think you need an `Extension method` for this, you can simply have a method in your Invoice class to `CalculateTotal` on the `Invoice` you pass in.

Something like:

```
var calculatedInvoice = Invoice.CalculateTotal(bookingProcessModel.Invoice);
```

The `CalculateTotal` would return a new Invoice with the values calculated.

If you want to stick with the extension method, you will need to assign the return value.

Comment: Nope.That is not the problem,hence all the properties are reference type.If your argument is right,then how can it be updated correctly when I put a debug on the extension method ? Problem may be in somewhere else ? Do you have any clue ? :(